# Tablesorter.js / simple Javascript table sorting equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm looking for a tablesorting Javascript library and of everything I've seen I like [tablesorter.js](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). I'm afraid to use this, however, because it looks as if it hasn't been updated in quite some time. Does anybody still use this library/know if it still works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested, I do have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which I have been actively maintaining.

Depending on what functionality you want, I would say my fork has a "moderate" amount of functionality.

There are [many other alternatives](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/) most are very simple, but if you need a script with extensive functionality, take a look at [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: Ah, that's great thank you. I don't know how I missed that. I'm really just looking for some bare-bones, tiny, sorting-and-nothing-else, library, so I'm thinking I'll go with tablesorter.